# Angular page doesn't refresh after data is added or removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a recurrent problem with my angular app whereby it doesn't refresh the page after data has been added, edited or removed. So if I add a new item to a list of subjects, the new item doesn't appear on the list unless I navigate away from the page and then come back to it. I've tried using route.reload and then resetting the scope of the subjects list below. I put in an alert to see if it get fired- but the alert appears before the page redirects back to the list of subjects, which is strange as $location.path('/subjects') is two lines before it. Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('SubjectEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'SubjectFactory', 'SubjectsFactory', '$location', '$route',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, SubjectFactory, SubjectsFactory, $location, $route) {

    // callback for ng-click 'updateSubject':

    $scope.updateSubject = function () {

//Performs an update to the server
        SubjectFactory.update($scope.subject);
//Redirects to list of all subjects
        $location.path('/subjects/');
//Should reset the scope of the subject list
        $scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();
//Should reload the page
        $route.reload();
//For debugging- the alert appears BEFORE the redirect to list of all subjects happens
        alert('route reload happening');
    };


    SubjectFactory.show({id: $routeParams.subjectId}).$promise.then(function(subject) {
        $scope.subject = subject;
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });


}]);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

EDIT: Subjects Service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.services');

app.factory('SubjectsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myapiurl.com/subjects', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

app.factory('SubjectFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myapiurl.com/subjects/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
        update: { method: 'PATCH', params: {id: '@id'} },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you past SubjectFactory as well?

Comment: BTW what format do you send subjects? see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http JSON Vulnerability Protection

Comment: I just send them as a block of JSON I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the structure of the requests slightly fixed the problem- so instead of

```
$scope.updateSubject = function () {
    SubjectFactory.update($scope.subject);
    $location.path('/subjects/');
    $scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();
    $route.reload();
};
```

It is now

```
$scope.updateSubject = function () {
                SubjectFactory.update($scope.subject).$promise.then(function (subject) {
                    $scope.subject = subject;
                    $location.path('/subjects/');
                    $route.reload();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 4):

Some times you need to apply changes to scope this is done by the following code:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

But this can be done only if it's not in "$digest" phase, otherwise it will throw exception. So you need to check first it's not in "$digest" phase then you can apply it. Here is the example of the code I use for safe applying changes:

```
safeApply: function (scope, callback) {
   if (scope.$$phase != '$apply' && scope.$$phase != '$digest' &&
        (!scope.$root || (scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest'))) {
        scope.$apply();
    }
    if (angular.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: I included $scope.apply() but it had no effect on the refresh and no exception was thrown!

Comment: did you add $scope.$apply() after this line?

$scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();

Comment: Yes, I'm now getting a console error- TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'apply'

Comment: you forgot to add "$" sign before apply. $scope.$apply()

Comment: D'oh. Now I'm getting Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress. Presume that means it's in $digest phase? Either way, the page doesn't refresh..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest next way:

You can't get data from database, after adding, you can easly push new added object to `$scope.items`.

**Example:**

```
 $scope.add = function (newItem) {
        DataService.addItem(newItem).then(function(){
           $scope.items.push(newItem);
           //or for removing
           //$scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(newItem), 1);
        });
    };
```

And adjust your factory:

```
   addItem: function (newProject) {
        $http.post('Api/Controller/Post').then(function(successResult){ 
             ...
        }, function (errorResult) {
           ...
        });
    }
```

Item will be added in `$scope.items` only after **success** calling of server-side method.